# Unclickable Menu link keeps refreshing my page

Tags: navigation

Hello and sorry for my bad English. I am using Drupal 8 and i want to make a menu with categories. The menu title has to be CATEGORIES and when someone click on it, the menu has to show the categories with a drop down. So i've created categories. Then i created a menu called - CATEGORIES and i marked "show as expanded". In the menu link i added - "**`route:<nolink>`**" . So now i have Categories menu with drop down listing categories, but when i click on it, the page is refreshed. I dont whant the page to be refreshed everytime i click on CATEGORIES. I just want to show me the drop down and not refreshing the page... I am using this theme https://www.drupal.org/project/news_zymphonies_theme and if you click on Live demo you can see in main navigation the menu link - "LAYOUT". When you click on it, the menu shows 2 categories - "two sidebar" and "left , right". In my case when i click on LAYOUT will show me this two categories but it will refresh the page too and i dont want to refresh it. How to fix that? Please help me i've readed so many topics and didn't find a solution :(

Comment: When you hover over the menu item, what do you see in the status bar? E.g. what is the HREF of the link? If it's anything other than # it's going to navigate the browser somewhere unless a click event cancels it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i've solved the problem for now. I've just typed `##` in "CATEGORIES" link instead of one `#`. Now when i click on CATEGORIES, the page is not refreshing and a drop down menu appears.